# Pinescript, how to set and indicator value to modify only when entering a new position and not when the indicator is changing?

Tags: pine-script

I have this problem: my indicator show the lowest low of last 83 candles since a new crossover between the two ema. The strategy.entry is set at the crossover, and i wanna set the stop loss al the lowest low of the last 83 candles since entry. The problem occur when I have already an open position and there is a new crossover between the emas. So the stop indicator change his value, based on the new crossover.

Here the code and a photo.

```
en//@version=4 

strategy("My strategy", overlay=true)

ema1 = ema(close, 40)
ema2 = ema(close, 70)
ema1Smooth = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ema1, barmerge.gaps_on, 
barmerge.lookahead_off)
ema2Smooth = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ema2, barmerge.gaps_on, 
barmerge.lookahead_off)

Stop = valuewhen(crossover(ema1Smooth, ema2Smooth), lowest(low, 83), 0) 
ProfitT = strategy.position_avg_price*1.003 

strategy.entry("Buy", long=true, when=crossover(ema1Smooth, ema2Smooth))
strategy.exit("Buy", limit=ProfitT, stop=Stop)

plot(ema1Smooth, "Fast", color.orange)
plot(ema2Smooth, "Slow", color.blue)
plot(Stop, "Stop", color.red)
```

[image]

So, my aim is to fix the Stop value when entering a position, and keep it the same even if a new crossover occur. I tried the valuewhen function. Thank You for your answers.

Comment: When does this happen? Can you share your tickerid, timeframe and the actual date when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stop` variable does not change its value based on the new crossover. It is changing value every bar, that is how Pine works. To achieve what you want you have to stop the `Stop` variable changing on every bar unconditionally.

Check if you are already in a position using `strategy.position_size`. If this is greater than zero, you are in a long position, and if it is less than zero, you are in a short position. So you need to check for 0.

I would change this:

```
Stop = valuewhen(crossover(ema1Smooth, ema2Smooth), lowest(low, 83), 0)
```

To this:

```
var float Stop = na
if (strategy.position_size == 0) // if True we are not in any position
    Stop := valuewhen(crossover(ema1Smooth, ema2Smooth), lowest(low, 83), 0) // watch the 4 spaces at the beginning of the line
```

Because it is undetermined if the `Stop` variable will be conditionally set in a calculation round, it is best to set it anyway and let the condition work it out. Other part of your script might need a guard against the `na` value, but it is better to use `na` instead of some synthetic low value as you could select a security/crypto derivative where that would still be a viable value (and cause super strange behavior).
Be sure to put this conditional block *before* the `strategy.entry` line.

Comment: Ty Man, I resolved with this: Stop = valuewhen(crossover(ema1Smooth, ema2Smooth) and strategy.position_size == 0, lowest(low, 83), 0).
Which is the same concept of your suggestion, so ty for your help!

Comment: It would be interesting to check as programming languages can optimize the evaluation of conditionals. When they decide that the whole conditional will be false or true (and cannot change whatever the next conditional is) they stop processing conditionals. So beware, as the first part of the conditional might be still calculated every time as the interpreter cannot decide if the whole conditional is false or true. If you experience issues, change the order of the conditionals, and put the position.size check first.